MkDocs Build Fails in GitHub Actions: Config value 'docs_dir' Error
Code:
Run mkdocs build -f mkdocs/mkdocs.yml
mkdocs build -f mkdocs/mkdocs.yml
shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
env:
pythonLocation: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.3/x64
PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.3/x64/lib/pkgconfig
Python_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.3/x64
Python2_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.3/x64
Python3_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.3/x64
LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.3/x64/lib
ERROR   -  Config value 'docs_dir': The path 'mkdocs/Docs' isn't an existing directory.
Aborted with a configuration error!
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
enter image description here
Check the Current Directory Structure:
Verify and Update mkdocs.yml:
docs_dir: mkdocs/Docs
mkdir -p mkdocs/Docs
echo "# Welcome to MkDocs" > mkdocs/Docs/index.md
but it's does not work for me
Work flow file
name: MK Docs
on:
push:
branches:
- main
tags:
- ""
- "Documentation-"
pull_request_target:
jobs:
build:
name: Build MkDocs
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
  - name: Checkout repo
    uses: actions/checkout@v4

  - name: Setup Python
    uses: actions/setup-python@v5
    with:
      python-version: '3.x'

  - name: Cache dependencies
    uses: actions/cache@v4
    with:
      path: ~/.cache/pip
      key: ${{ runner.os }}-pip-${{ hashFiles('mkdocs/requirements.txt') }}
      restore-keys: |
        ${{ runner.os }}-pip-
  - name: Install dependencies
    run: pip install -r mkdocs/requirements.txt

  - name: Build MK Docs project
    run: mkdocs build -f mkdocs/mkdocs.yml

  - name: Upload MK Docs build files
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
    with:
      name: mkdocs-files
      path: ./mkdocs/site

deploy:
name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
needs: build
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/v') || startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/Documentation-')
steps:
  - name: Download MkDocs artifact
    uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
    with:
      name: mkdocs-files
      path: ./mkdocs/site

  - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
    uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
    with:
      github_token: ${{ secrets.GH_PAGES_TOKEN }}
      publish_dir: ./mkdocs/site


You're not showing your workflow, so it's hard to tell. Are you perhaps missing a step to check out your repository?
